# Error while using pywebhdfs package in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, hdfs, webhdfs

I am trying to use pywebhdfs module in Spyder to interact with hdfs directly to list the files and folders. I have established the connection to the server. My code is:

```
from pywebhdfs.webhdfs import PyWebHdfsClient
from pprint import pprint
hdfs=PyWebHdfsClient(host='10.242.245.199',port='50070',
                     user_name='s733390')
my_dir = 'user/s733390'
pprint(hdfs.list_dir(my_dir))
```

but when I run this code I am getting this error:

> PyWebHdfsException: `b'<HEAD><TITLE>internal error - server connection terminated</TITLE></HEAD>\n<BODY BGCOLOR="white" FGCOLOR="black"><H1>internal error - server connection terminated</H1><HR>\n<FONT FACE="Helvetica,Arial"><B>\nDescription: internal error - server connection terminated</B></FONT>\n<HR>\n<!-- default "internal error - server connection terminated" response (502) -->\n</BODY>\n                                                                                                                                                                                                                    \x00'`

no other hdfs commands are working and giving me this error. Can anyone help me remove this error?

Comment: HI, facing similar issue, Did u find the solution?  or root cause of the problem?